# Splitting subtitle files with dialogs to strings (or files) in Python

Tags: python, python-re, subtitle

I have a collection of subtitle files that contain dialogues, like this:

```
1
00:00:02,460 --> 00:00:07,020
JOHN: Great.

2
00:00:07,020 --> 00:00:11,850
How are you today? 
JANE: Quite alright. 
JOHN: Perfect.

3
00:00:11,850 --> 00:00:17,230
Had a busy day?

4
00:00:17,230 --> 00:00:28,070
JANE: Not so much. And you?

5
00:00:28,070 --> 00:00:32,300
JOHN: Mine was okay too. Gimme a few extra minutes.
```

I would like to extract only, for example, **JANE**, and then both, and to have a resulting string or file, like this:

```
Quite alright 
Not so much
And you
```

And then both speakers combined, like this:

```
Great
How are you today
Quite alright
Perfect
Had a busy day
Not so much
And you
Mine was okay too
Gimme a few extra minutes
```

So, the result is sentence per line and interpunctions removed (all but `'`, which are kept for contractions; e.g., `don't`).

Effectively, I have managed to *clean* from interpunctions and numbers/timestamps. I've been using RegEx (`infile` is input file; first `re.sub()` is to tidy up instances where there is no space after the interpunction):

```
for line in infile:
    if not line[0].isnumeric():
        line = re.sub('(?<=[,;:.!?])(?=[a-zA-Z])', r' ', line)
        lines += re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\'\ \n]+', r'', line)
```

Sadly, I haven't found any elegant way to condition and extract lines that belong to one specific speaker. In principle, I would like to be able to choose whether all will be saved to the same string/file, each speaker to a separate string/file (or one speaker only).

Comment: Is that the exact format of a particular file?  What are the rules for breaking up the dialogue into those "numbered blocks"?   If you know those rules, the problem is very straightforward...

Comment: Hi, [Buzz Moschetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2502126/buzz-moschetti), yes this is the exact format (of all files), as I have copied the excerpt. The first number is just the order of the subtitle, and the next line contains the beginning and the end of presenting that subtitle on the screen. How exactly the timing is "decided" I really do not know. I guess, when the speaker changes, or after a long pause, or given the fact that any subtitle can contain only so many characters in two rows etc. (much like Twitter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just have to keep sniffing for change of speaker and build up a nice array of structured data:

```
    current_speaker = None
    dialogue = []
    while(True):
        the_line = fetchLine(fromWhever)
        if the_line is None:
            break

        if the_line == '':
            continue
        if the_line.isnumeric():
            fetchLine(fromWherever)  # Get the timeline that follows a block count                                       
            continue  # ignore it all for now                                                                   

        # Actual speaker line.                                                                                  
        m = re.search("^(\S+):", the_line)
        if m is not None:
            spk = m.groups()[0]

            current_speaker = spk
            the_line = the_line[len(spk)+2:] # remove name, colon, and 1 space                                  

        dialogue.append({"spk":current_speaker,"text":the_line})

    print(dialogue)

[{'spk': 'JOHN', 'text': 'Great.'}, {'spk': 'JOHN', 'text': 'How are you today? '}, {'spk': 'JANE', 'text': 'Quite alright. '}, {'spk': 'JOHN', 'text': 'Perfect.'}, {'spk': 'JOHN', 'text': 'Had a busy day?'}, {'spk': 'JANE', 'text': 'Not so much. And you?'}, {'spk': 'JOHN', 'text': 'Mine was okay too. Gimme a few extra minutes.'}]
```

After this, it is a simple matter of post-processing the array to turn sentences into more entries or write to a file, etc.